# Send 500 FB friends in jsonArray to server

Tags: android, facebook

In our application I need to get Facebook friends from Facebook server and send all friends to PHP server. I am able to send list of Facebook friends to server only if I have a small list of friends e.g:--30 Friends, in case of large e.g.--500 friends, it is not able to send list to server. The code that I used to send data to server is :

```
 json.put("UserId",SAVING_INFO_PREF.getString("USER_ID",""));

            for(int i=0;i<Friends_ID.size();i++)
            {
                JSONObject newjson = new JSONObject();
                newjson.put("facebookId",Friends_ID.get(i).toString());
                newjson.put("facebookUserName",Friends_Name.get(i));
                newjson.put("userThumbnailUrl",Friends_ThumbURL.get(i));
                jsArray.put(newjson);
            }   
            json.put("facebookfriends", jsArray);
```

So I am stuck here. Any idea, will be appreciated.

Comment: why you are not able to send? Whats happening? Any issue if yes then post logcat here.

Comment: I had a funny issue - I could not insert in SQLite more than 500 rows at once

Comment: Thanks for replying.. No i am able to send only if i have small amount of data.. I am not getting any error or exception or out of memoryException. When i am sending data it is not received at server end.

Comment: we have same application in iphone. it is sending this large amount of data on php server successfully. I have to do it in same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had same problem while sending fbFriends to server. Actually problem was that my array contained special characters. I have not specified character set in stringEntity function.

```
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
```

Answer (score 1):

> In our application i need to get facebook friends from facebook server and send all friends to php server.

Why don’t you have the “php server” *get* the data himself, this way eliminating the need to send that data around a second time …?

Comment: Good point but my guess is access violations. The user gives access from app but that doesn't include the server...

Comment: Permissions are tied to a specific app id, not physical devices.